# Fetch data from Post API endpoint from Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, api, spring-boot

I'm trying to fetch data from API endpoint using Spring Boot application, by API endpoint accept 'POST' method with body. This is the format how the API endpoint accepts the body to be:

```
{
    "queryType": "scan",
    "dataSource": "EmpActive",
    "intervals": "2008-03-18T12:04:00.000Z/2009-10-23T14:39:00.000Z"

}
```

This is my Spring Boot code:

```
public String responde() {
    String uri = "http://10.68.192.208:8082/druid/v2/";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MultiValueMap<Object, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    bodyMap.add("queryType", "scan");
    bodyMap.add("dataSource", "EmpActive");
    bodyMap.add("intervals","2008-03-18T12:04:00.000Z/2009-10-23T14:39:00.000Z");
    System.out.println(bodyMap);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<Object, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    JSONPObject resp = rest.postForObject(uri, request, JSONPObject.class);
    return bodyMap.toString();
}
```

The API response object (Obtained using Postman)

```
    [
    {
        "segmentId": "EmpActive_2008-11-17T00:00:00.000Z_2008-11-18T00:00:00.000Z_2019-07-19T11:55:30.083Z",
        "columns": [
            "__time",
            "dtason",
            "intempdimkey"
        ],
        "events": [
            {
                "__time": 1226947200000,
                "dtason": "1020124800000",
                "intempdimkey": "101326"
            },
            {
                "__time": 1226947200000,
                "dtason": "1020124800000",
                "intempdimkey": "101327"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

But I'm receiving Error code 500.